# Sendgrid Event Webhook sends fake emails response and not real data

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have created a post api and did put that post api inside the event webhook settings of sendgrid. But when i enabled it and check the json response on my api in local, i am getting fake messages and not real data.
Anyone know whats the reason. I checked their documentation, it is not telling anything else.
Source of information : https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/

Comment: Post your configuration screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using event webhook according to above documentation in the question. You wont get the real data as for testing purpose sendgrid sends that data from your account. Instead try implementing the API. Then you will get the real response as it would contain your sendgrid api key.